# Корректно ли работать с тегом ?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Мне нужно сделать затемнение всей страницы и выводить на экран сообщение, но  абсолютно позиционированный див не желает растягиваться на ширину всей странницы, по этому я решил попробовать затемнить <html>. Так вот:
Какие проблемы может вызвать подобная практика(и вызовет ли?)

Comment: Парсер съел <html> в заголовке((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего сделать через див. Ну, а если вашим способом, то затемняйте не html, а body.
Я использую вот такой стиль для маски:

```
.modalMask {
    background-color: #666666;
    opacity: .50;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 768px;
    min-width: 1024px;
    z-index: 9998;
    display: none;
}
```

Идет она у меня сразу после body:

Comment: Да, я тоже так думал сделать, только про фильтр для IE забыл...
Проблема в том, что body, отказывается растягиваться на всю ширину экрана.
Но это видимо мой косяк в коде, пойду искать его.....

Comment: Конечно, какая-то ошибка. Боди легко тянется на всю площадь браузера. Удачи с нахождением, если что, обращайтесь. И вопрос не забывайте закрывать.

Comment: Понял проблему. Блок с абсолютным позиционированием и высотой 100% растягивается по ширине экрана, т.е. той части страницы, которую мы видим. Не сталкивались с подобным? Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно рястянуть затемнение на высоту, которая больше чем высота экрана, к примеру экран по высоте 768px, а высота body 2000px, то только через добавление  style="height:2000px" к блоку с затемнением:

```
...
<body>
    <div class="modalMask" style="height:2000px"></div>
    ...
</body>
...
```

и сделать это можно через javascript добавляя значение height, стандартными средствами css не получится.